# sort this array from highest to lowest

Tags: php, laravel

so i make an apriori algorithm, and this is the result.

[image: array picture]

this is the code where i get this array from.

```
$count = array_count_values($arrayCount);

$array = [];

foreach($count as $key => $value){
    $confidence = ($value/$count_antecedent);
    $support = ($value/$count_all_transactions);
   
    $isi = [
        $key=>$confidence*$support
    ];
    array_push($array,$isi);
}



return $array;
```

i want to sort it from highest to lowest but also keeping the key.

if this array is sorted all i need is to take 4 highest number.

it will look like this (if sorted) :

```
  $i = 0;
 foreach($sortedArray as $key => $value){
    if($i == 0){
     $product1 == product::find($key);
    }
    else if($i == 1){
     $product2 = product::find($key);
    }
    else if($i == 2){
    $product3 = product::find($key);
    }
   else if($i == 3){
    $product4 = product::find($key);
   }
   $i++;
 }
```

Comment: maybe i need to change the $isi variable to ["value"=>$confidence*$support,"key"=>$key] and then use usort ?

Comment: oh yeah its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so in order to order the array i need to use usort where the key name should be the same in every array.

so i changed the $isi variable to

```
$isi = ["value"=>$confidence*$support,"key"=>$key];
```

and then use this usort function to order the array

```
usort($array,function($a,$b){
 return $a["value"] < $b["value"];
})
```

and then to get 4 highest product from db there slighly change to the code

```
  $i = 0;
 foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if($i == 0){
     $product1 = product::find($value['key']);
    }
    else if($i == 1){
     $product2 = product::find($value['key']);
    }
    else if($i == 2){
    $product3 = product::find($value['key']);
    }
   else if($i == 3){
    $product4 = product::find($value['key']);
   }
   $i++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `arsort($array)` function.

It's all you need.

Comment: tried it didn't work, it become 1 and not even an array

Comment: I think you have an object not an array

Comment: i edited the post maybe somethings wrong with my code

Comment: Use it this way
`$array[] = $confidence*$support;`
and remove the `$isi` variable.

Comment: how about the key? i need to keep the key, because thats the product id

Comment: In this case you may use something like `$array[$key] = $confidence*$support;`

Comment: i thought its working but then i realize it just reading the array key from lowest order.
tried this with asort and still return 1